# Why am I getting a redirection loop from PHP built-in web server on AWS Cloud9?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect

This is my first attempt to migrate a project from Cloud9 to AWS Cloud9 since the clock is ticking.

I have created a brand new environment on AWS Cloud9, which is supposed to work out of the box. I've uploaded WordPress files and database, replaced URLs with my environment's preview URL (https://*.vfs.cloud9.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com), then ran the build with a PHP (built-in web server) runner.

Usually, that's all that is needed to migrate a WordPress website but this time I am stuck in a redirection loop whenever I try to preview the site.

My findings so far are that it's all down to forced SSL by AWS Cloud9. They specifically said they won't allow for any environment to work over a non-secure connection.

When I set the home_url in the options table to "http://...", then the loop breaks and the site appears. Of course, assets don't load because of the insecure connection. However, when I switch back to https in the home_url value, I am back in the loop...

No matter what I put in .htaccess, it doesn't help. I can't even find where to config Apache as the default /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf refers to /var/www directory, where as AWS C9's default workspace dir is /home/ec2-user/environment.

Below is a screenshot of my console while it's stuck in the loop. It does numerous connection to itself (duh..) and finally terminates.

[image: console]

Comment: Please provide your htaccess rules, if you think it is htaccess error.

Comment: At the moment my htaccess file is empty

Comment: can you throw light on what ami are you using , where did you get ssl and how you configured it as it is https ?

Comment: Sure. When you create a new environment in AWS C9 it defaults to Amazon Linux OS, so that's the AMI I am using at the moment. I believe they may have modified it as it comes with built-in web server and many more features. Also, there is no need to configure any SSL as it, again, comes default when you launch a new environment in AWS Cloud9.

This is directly from the documentation: "To help improve code safety, in the address box of the application preview tab in the IDE, AWS Cloud9 always uses https. This behavior cannot be changed."

Comment: I noticed one more thing as I try to figure this out. Whenever the home_url value in database matches the browser requested url, that is both have http or https at the same time, you get the redirection loop. Odd?

Comment: Okey another update - it seems like we are talking about PHP built-in web server, not Apache. It still doesn't explain the redirection loop, but points us towards the right tool.